# how can i await a void containing download function by altohttp library in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

how can i await void of downloading in [alttohttp](https://github.com/aalitor/AltoHttp) library in c# .net?

when I was using WebClient it was working to make await before the code and it awaits to finish the download but in [Alttohttp](https://github.com/aalitor/AltoHttp) library it doesn't await due to it's a void.

this is the code :

```
httpdownloader = new HttpDownloader(uri, filename);
 httpdownloader.DownloadCompleted += htppdownloaderU_Completed; 
httpdownloader.ProgressChanged += httpdownloaderU_Progress;
 httpdownloader.StatusChanged += httpdownloader_StatusChanged;
 await httpdownloader.Start(); // then after finishing the whole download
```

i want this code to continue the void code after finishing the download by this library

Comment: You cannot await `void` methods. The library you are using is using an event pattern. If awaiting is really needed, then the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern should be considered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-overview

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to excecute something after the httpdownloader is done.
If so, you can add your code in httpdownloaderU_Completed which is a delegate function that will be excecuted after your download is completed. Something like this:

```
 void httpdownloaderU_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   MessageBox.Show("Download comleted!");
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you misunderstand how the library work. It is event-driven, so the only way to know if the download is complete is to check when the code enters the `htppdownloaderU_Completed` method. if you really want to continue after calling the `Start()` method, maybe you can have a global variable for the class that you set in that Method like

```
IsDownloadComplete = true;
```

and then instead of trying to do this:

```
await httpdownloader.Start();
```

you can do a while loop to wait for the download to complete.
something like

```
httpdownloader.Start(); 
while(IsDownloadComplete == false)
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
}

// Download is now complete, do something with the download
DoSomething();
```

but is probably not the most ideal way, and you should probably rethink, and just do everything you want to do after the download is complete from the  `htppdownloaderU_Completed` method

Comment: If awaiting is really needed, then the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern should be considered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-overview

Comment: i need to add more thing that i made a loop for the function that download bec it download by a variables enterd to download many files in the loop so i want it download one by one so this is the reason that made me not to use completed event

Comment: the void is in a loop and it downloads many files so when loop start it starts all files in same time and this makes a timed error and problem in progress bar etc